# Jquery ajax method success data

Tags: jquery, ajax

Ajax method for a search system.

```
function PostForm()
{
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url : "assets/server.php",
    data : $("#frm").serialize(),
    success : function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
    var data = data.split("||");
    $(".firstinfo").html(data[0]);
    $(".secondinfo").html(data[1]);

    }
 },"json");
}
```

I am working with this piece of code. But i can't figure out what these three lines are actually doing.

```
var data = data.split("||");
    $(".firstinfo").html(data[0]);
    $(".secondinfo").html(data[1]);
```

why it splits with pipe sign? I guess success method returns an array and it shows data in firstinfo, secondinfo divs. I am working with a search system actually. Please can anyone explain me the above mentioned codes with the points i mentioned?

Comment: you ought to ask whomsoever implemented `assets/server.php`

Comment: In fact, it's just a - not too professional - way of returning two datas.

Comment: data.split("||"); searches for String "||" in data and splits the String when "||" is ancountered, resulting in an array of 0 to n length. The code presumes there is always one "||" in the response, spliting the string in two parts, giving back an array with index 0 (for the first part) and index 1 (for the second part), which are then writen into any element with class firstinfo and secondinfo.

Comment: [mondjunge](http://stackoverflow.com/users/503865/mondjunge) is correct, your response (check console in dev tools, F12) should look like this: `String: First info content||Second info value`. After splitting, you get an array: `["First info content", "Second info value"]`

Comment: btw. this is bad practice, but I also do this in a project to receive 2 datasets in one ajax call. XD

Comment: In my older projects I also did this, but now I prefer json_encode on server side. It's much cleaner to work with. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call Assets/server.php you are doing  a Post to that page and the post has a response (see the codeo of that page) analizing your code it seemas that the response, which is the var data comes in this format: [value1] || [value2] ||..[valuex]
Then you have this array of values and you show them in your html saying that all the elements with Class "firstinfo" will show first value of data array (data[0]) and elements with class "secondinfo" will show second value of data array (data[1](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)).
More information about this:
[http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> data
>   Type: PlainObject or String or Array
>   Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

Comment: Thank you all. I have understood it now. I really appreciate all of your quick and detailed replies.